# Is it possible to include Internet Explorer 5 or 6 in Selenium Grid?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, selenium3

Based on this question here, I was wondering if you can also include Internet Explorer 5/6 in Selenium Grid?

[How can Internet Explorer 5 be emulated in 2020?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42112/how-can-internet-explorer-5-be-emulated-in-2020)

I don't think this is possible either, but maybe someone has implemented this with Selenium Grid?

Comment: What is the difference between your question and the linked one? Only that you need IE6?

Comment: The question is specifically directed towards Selenium Grid. So it is a supplement to the other question and to be seen apart from it.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/ and you will find sction which browsers are officialy supported by selenium. For IE it is "Only version 11 is supported, and it requires additional configuration."